# matplotlib, reusing lines in different figures

Tags: matplotlib

The intent is to create, in an optimal way, a number of detailed figures and a summary figure where you can compare the relative size of the different solutions.

To show you what I want, I've made up the following minimal example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

parameters = [2, 3]
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 501)

f_all = plt.figure()
a_all = f_all.add_subplot(111)

for p in parameters:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    l, = ax.plot(t, np.sin(p*t)/p,
                 label='$\\omega=%d,\\quad{p}_0=%5.3f$'%(p,1./p))
    a_all.add_line(l)
    ax.legend()
    fig.savefig('pippo_%d'%p)

a_all.legend()
f_all.savefig('pippo_a')
```

the expected result consists of 3 figures, two with a sine curve each, spanning the [0,5] interval, and one with the two curves combined.

OTOH, below you can find what I've got.   Of course there is something (a very fundamental something!) that I'm missing.

I could take a different approach, using an `a_all.plot(...)` in the inner loop (tested, it works!), but now I'm curiuous if there is a way to reuse a line and I'm here, seeking for your help.

[image: pippo_2]

[image: pippo_3]

[image: pippo_a]

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the fact that only very small parts of the lines are plotted only occurs when you add the lines also to `a_all` (i.e. it works as expected if you comment the line `a_all.add_line(l)`)?

Comment: I used _alternatively_ `a_all.add_line(...)`  and, in a version that I haven't posted, `a_all,plot(...)` and yes, in the 1st case I got the cutted lines,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the line to `a_all` after you save the first figure:

```
for p in parameters:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    l, = ax.plot(t, np.sin(p*t)/p,
                 label='$\\omega=%d,\\quad{p}_0=%5.3f$'%(p,1./p))
    ax.legend()
    fig.savefig('pippo_%d'%p)
    a_all.add_line(l)
```

EDIT:

Then, you need to set the transform for the new lines on `a_all` to move them to the new axis. You'll probably also need to manually set the x and y limits.

Here's the complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

parameters = [2, 3]
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 501)

f_all = plt.figure()
a_all = f_all.add_subplot(111)

for p in parameters:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    l, = ax.plot(t, np.sin(p*t)/p,
                 label='$\\omega=%d,\\quad{p}_0=%5.3f$'%(p,1./p))
    ax.legend()
    fig.savefig('pippo_%d.png'%p)
    a_all.add_line(l)

[newline.set_transform(a_all.transData) for newline in a_all.lines]

a_all.set_xlim(0,5)
a_all.set_ylim(-1,1)

a_all.legend()
f_all.savefig('pippo_a.png')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom, we have made a progress: the individual plots are now correct using either of your suggestions but for me, python 2.7.10 and matplotlib 1.4.2, the combined plot is _identical_ , in both cases, to the one I showed in my question --- I also tried a combination, first `savefig` and then `add_line(copy(l))` but also in this case the combined plot is _identical_ to the one I posted.

Comment: Oh well, I cannot accept this as a solution to my problem but it's a step in the right direction, isn't it?

Comment: @gboffi: See my edit. I think that setting the `transform` for your new lines should work

Comment: Tom! I can't think how you came up with a solution in 20' or less, when after all this time I've almost forgotten _my_ question... Thank you, ciao